# Modify path in 'screen'

Tags: bash, environment-variables, anaconda

In bash I am using ssh to access a cluster then conda environments and inside these I use 'screen'. One of my installed programmes is failing to run because 'screen' has a different path set. it runs fine outside 'screen'. I think miniconda did this when it installed the programme. I've looked through all the docs and can't find a way to remove the first two or three sections of the $PATH which I think are causing the issue. I can't track down the file containing the lines to remove.

Without 'screen' echo $PATH gives;

```
/home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/home/ubuntu/perl5/bin:/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/roary-three/bin:/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/condabin:/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

When in 'screen' I get a version of;

```
/home/ubuntu/perl5/bin:/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/bin:/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/roary-three/bin:/home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/home/ubuntu/perl5/bin:/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/condabin:/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Can anyone help me to remove these lines?

**Update;**
I have managed to make the program work by using

```
export PATH=/home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/home/ubuntu/perl5/bin:/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/roary-three/bin:/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/condabin:/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

but I'm not sure how to make this permanent in 'screen' as I don't know which file it's modifying.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at [other people's solutions](https://serverfault.com/a/226788/75891), it seems that `screen` sources `~/.bashrc` **or** `~/.bash_profile` for different people.

Do you have anything in your `~/.screenrc` dealing with "shell"?  Can you tell us in which of your dot files is the proper `$PATH` created.  You need to ensure that `screen` sources this file and it's hard to give you definitive instructions without knowing which file gives you the proper `$PATH`.

---

You should make sure that your `~/.bash_profile` `source`s your `~/.bashrc` file.  You can learn more about the [difference between these two files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51036/what-is-the-difference-between-bash-profile-and-bashrc), but in summary, the `~/.bash_profile` file is sourced when you login via `ssh`, so either put your configurations in that file, or have it source your main file (`~/.bashrc`).

```bsh
$ cat ~/.bash_profile 
#
# ~/.bash_profile
#

[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && source ~/.bashrc
```

*Note*: You may also be interested in learning about `~/.profile`, `~/.xsessionrc` and `~/.xinitrc` as well, but that is not needed for your current goals.

Comment: Thanks for this help. If I understand this correctly ~/.bash_profile should be sourced at first ssh. Are you saying that when I then login to a 'screen' the ~/.bashrc file is sourced?    I do not have a ~/.bash_profile file, but I do have a ~./profile file which looks as if it might be doing the same thing. It has the lines:     " if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc""
which I think do the same thing as you have suggested.  In this case then I think I need to modify the ~/.bashrc file.

Comment: Yeah, so you can try duplicating that so that `~/.bash_profile` is also sourced, assuming `~/.bash_profile` is what gives your your proper `$PATH`.